# What's wrong with XUL reference?

Tags: reference, xul

Why the `oncommand` is not discribed in [Xul button reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/button) page?

It's even used in an example, but it's not docummented with the other methods, am I looking the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documented under MDC - XUL attributes ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/oncommand)).